# Python/Tkinter: Is it possible to detect when an OptionMenu/Menubutton popup gets closed via clicking outside of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter so please bare with me (Python 3.8.5/Tkinter 8.6 sample code at the end of the post - There is also an **Edited Version**)

I'm trying to change & keep highlighted the button-bg while the user interacts with the menu, and reset it only after the menu goes away.

This picture shows what I mean (default behavior on the left, mine on the right)

[image]

I've researched and tried several things and I've managed to make it partially work. It's not shown in the pic, but additionally the button-bg gets reset when the user closes the menu by selecting an option. However, I cannot detect when the menu gets closed via a click outside the menu.

What I'm doing in the code below, is setting the button's `activebackground` upon creation and also forcing it as `bg` in the `postcommand` option. Then I add an on-click callback to all menu-items (via their `command` option) which resets the button's bg. Apparently, the `command` callback overwrites their default one, so I'm additionally updating manually the `StringVar()` of the `OptionMenu`.

I have so many unanswered questions, **but the main one** is how can I catch the case where the menu gets closed without an option being clicked, so I can reset the button-bg? Everything else works as intended.

And a few more questions if I may:

2. Can we obtain the actual widget object of a menu-item? None of the `Menu` widget methods seem to return a menu-item widget (it could save me the overriding of the default callback, and thus updating manually the `StringVar()` since I could

> menuitem.bind("<Button-1>", callback, add="+")

instead of

> menu.entryconfigure(i, command=callback)

3. Is there a way of passing the event object to the callback when using the `command` option?
4. Do the `"<Leave>"` and `"<Enter>"` events even work on om['menu']? They didn't in my tries on Windows (btw same goes for the `.unpost()` method)

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Here comes the sample code

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_menuitem_click( bg, var ):
    global om, omvar
    om.configure( bg=bg )   # reset button's bg
    omvar.set( var )        # update manually

def add_menuitems_callback( menu, bg ):
    nitems = menu.index(tk.END) + 1
    for i in range (0, nitems):
        v = menu.entrycget( i, "label" )
        menu.entryconfigure( i, command = lambda bg=bg, v=v: on_menuitem_click(bg, v) )
     
root = tk.Tk()

# OptionMenu
omvar = tk.StringVar()
omvar.set( "Options" )
om = tk.OptionMenu( root, omvar, "One", "Two", "Three" )
abg = "light blue"
om.config( activebackground = abg )     # button's active-bg (onclick/onhover)
om.pack()

# add menu callback (force active-bg on the button when the menu pops up)
om['menu'].config( postcommand = lambda: om.config(bg=abg) )

# add menu-items callback (update omvar & reset button's bg when a menu-item is clicked)
add_menuitems_callback( om['menu'], om['bg'] )

# *** NEED TO ALSO RESET BUTTON's BG
# *** WHEN MENU CLOSES VIA OTHER MEANS
# *** (LIKE CLICKING OUTSIDE IT FOR EXAMPLE)

# show the beast
root.geometry( "360x200" )
root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364322/734848) by CommonSense, I realized that I can use the `command` option directly in the `OptionMenu` constructor, which completely eliminates the need of using the `add_menuitems_callback()`.

Moreover, the 1st argument of the callback is apparently **auto-passed** as the currently selected option at any given time, meaning there is no need of updating manually the `StringVar()` inside the callback (it is already auto-updated).

With that in mind, the code can be simplified as following (**the off-menu click detection issue remains**, but perhaps the rest prove handy in other cases):

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_menuitem_click( selected=None, bg=None ):
    global om, omvar
    om.configure( bg=bg )   # reset button's bg
    # omvar gets auto-updated (or use selected locally)
    print( f"'{ omvar.get() }' at index { om['menu'].index(omvar.get()) }" )
    # or print( f"{ selected } at index { om['menu'].index(selected) }" )

root = tk.Tk()

# OptionMenu
bg = root['bg']         # button's bg
abg = "light blue"      # button's activebackground (onclick/onhover)
omvar = tk.StringVar()
omvar.set( "Options" )
om = tk.OptionMenu( root, omvar, *("One", "Two", "Three"),
    # set menu-items onclick callback (reset button's bg)
    command= lambda sel, bg=bg: on_menuitem_click(sel, bg)
    )
om.config( bg= bg, activebackground= abg )
om.pack()

# set menu callback (force abg as bg when menu pops up)
om['menu'].config( postcommand = lambda: om.config(bg=abg) )

# *** NEED TO ALSO RESET BUTTON's BG
# *** WHEN MENU CLOSES VIA OTHER MEANS
# *** (LIKE CLICKING OUTSIDE IT FOR EXAMPLE)

# Show the beast
root.geometry( "360x200" )
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I catch the case where the menu gets closed without an option being clicked

I don't think it's possible. At least, not on every platform. On OSX and Windows the menu widget is a native widget (eg: not drawn by tkinter), and as such tkinter has very little visibility into what they do once they've been posted.

> Can we obtain the actual widget object of a menu-item?

No, because menu items aren't widgets.

> Is there a way of passing the event object to the callback when using the command= option?

No. If you want an event object you will need to use custom bindings rather than the `command` option.

> Do the "" and "" events even work on om['menu']?

Maybe on Linux, but not on OSX or Windows. Again, menus are handled by the underlying OS so tkinter essentially loses control once they are posted.

> ... They didn't in my tries on Windows (btw same goes for the .unpost() method)

The `unpost` method is documented to not work on Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan! A least now I know it cannot be done, so I can move on. Just a little clarification regarding menuitems, if I got it right, there is no way to attach more than one callback on them, right? Btw, them not being widgets was kind of a revelation :)